# `as.POSIXct` get error with `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` format

Tags: r, posixct

```
dates <- seq(1626629937,1626629944)

# CORRECT

## #1
as.POSIXct(dates,                    tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2021-07-19 01:38:57 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:58 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:59 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:00 CST"
#> [5] "2021-07-19 01:39:01 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:02 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:03 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:04 CST"

## #2
as.POSIXct(dates,                    tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01",optional = FALSE)
#> [1] "2021-07-19 01:38:57 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:58 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:59 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:00 CST"
#> [5] "2021-07-19 01:39:01 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:02 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:03 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:04 CST"


# DIFFERENT RESULT

## #3
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"                   ,origin="1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2021-07-18 17:38:57" "2021-07-18 17:38:58" "2021-07-18 17:38:59" "2021-07-18 17:39:00" "2021-07-18 17:39:01"
#> [6] "2021-07-18 17:39:02" "2021-07-18 17:39:03" "2021-07-18 17:39:04"


# NAs

## #4
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01")
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

## #5
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01",optional = FALSE)
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA


# ERROR

## #6
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"                                       ,optional = FALSE)
#>  Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(as.integer(.), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", optional = FALSE) : 
#>   'origin' must be supplied
```

As output of above R script,format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" with `tz`,`origin`,`optional` parameters cause `NA`.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy ones first:

- `optional = FALSE` is the default: therefore #1 == #2 and #4 == #5
- #6 needs no explanation: you need the argument `origin =` as the error states
- #3 returns different results because of the time zone (the `tz=` argument). Therefore, it shows 8 hours before.

Now, the problem is #4 and #5 (which are the same as I stated before):

```
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01")
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

To understand how this works you need to look at the function `as.POSIXct`, which, when called with  a numeric `x` (like in this case), calls the method: `as.POSIXct.numeric`.

```
as.POSIXct.numeric

#> function (x, tz = "", origin, ...) 
#> {
#>     if (missing(origin)) {
#>         if (!length(x)) 
#>             return(.POSIXct(numeric(), tz))
#>         if (!any(is.finite(x))) 
#>             return(.POSIXct(x, tz))
#>         stop("'origin' must be supplied")
#>     }
#>     .POSIXct(as.POSIXct(origin, tz = "GMT", ...) + x, tz)
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x55df7f23b390>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

Focus on this line:

```
#> .POSIXct(as.POSIXct(origin, tz = "GMT", ...) + x, tz)
```

In particular:

```
as.POSIXct(origin, tz = "GMT", ...) + x
```

As you see, the function transforms `origin` in datetime and then it sums the numeric input you imputed. Every additional argument you provided falls into `...`.

The function tries to convert `1970-01-01` to datetime using the format you provided: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.
Since the origin `1970-01-01` has format `%Y-%m-%d`, the function can't convert the origin from string to POSIX, thus returning `NA`. (That's where `NA`s are generated!)

When you convert a numeric to POSIX, the format you add as argument doens't apply to the output (since it will be always a POSIX) nor to the input, rather to the `origin`. Thus, `origin` and `format` need to match.

To solve your problem, you need to use `origin` with the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.
Like this:

```
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
#> [1] "2021-07-19 01:38:57 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:58 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:59 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:00 CST"
#> [5] "2021-07-19 01:39:01 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:02 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:03 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:04 CST"
```

Or you need to use this format: `%Y-%m-%d`
Like this:

```
as.POSIXct(dates,"%Y-%m-%d",tz="Asia/Shanghai",origin="1970-01-01")
#> [1] "2021-07-19 01:38:57 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:58 CST" "2021-07-19 01:38:59 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:00 CST"
#> [5] "2021-07-19 01:39:01 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:02 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:03 CST" "2021-07-19 01:39:04 CST"
```

The results are then equal to #1 and #2.